# Difference of asymptotics and Plancherel-Rotach asymptotics

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics

How do Plancherel-Rotach asymptotics differ from asymptotics of other type? Is there some definition or specific literature about asymptotics of "Plancherel-Rotach type"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Plancherel–Rotach-type asymptotics is for orthogonal polynomials. If $p_n(x)$ is the $n$th orthogonal polynomial in your sequence, the Plancherel–Rotach-type asymptotics will hold for large $n$ uniformly in $x$ provided $x$ is at most the size of the largest root of $p_n(x)$. So this type of asymptotics holds in the oscillatory region. There are other types of asymptotics for orthogonal polynomials that hold uniformly on the whole real line and they usually involve special functions (e.g., Airy or Bessel functions). Outside of orthogonal polynomials there are many other types of asymptotics. Thus, in summary, Plancherel–Rotach-type asymptotics is a special type of asymptotics.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification!